The concept `std::movable` evaluated to false for an empty class in Visual C++
My C++20 program works fine when compiled with GCC or Clang. But when I build it in Visual Studio, an unexpected compilation error occurs.
Maximally abbreviated example:
#include <concepts>

template<class T>
struct MyContainer {
    MyContainer() = default;
    explicit MyContainer( std::size_t ) requires( std::default_initializable<T> );
    void resize( std::size_t ) requires( std::movable<T> && std::default_initializable<T> ) {}
};

struct A;
struct B {
    MyContainer<A> c;
};
struct A{};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.c.resize( 42 );
}

MSVC error is
<source>(18): error C7500: 'resize': no function satisfied its constraints
<source>(7): note: could be 'void MyContainer<A>::resize(size_t)'
<source>(7): note: the 'MyContainer<A>::resize' constraint was not satisfied
<source>(7): note: the concept 'std::movable<A>' evaluated to false

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cs5Pa7xzv
Does the program contain something illegal or the error is incorrect?

I think that the problem is that at the point where MyContainer<A> c; is parsed, A is still only forward declared and incomplete (so the compiler cannot verify it respects the concept). The error disappears if you move A definition above Bs. At least it is not a general issue as hinted by the question's title.

If one must define A after the definition of B one could make A a template parameter. Then even MSVC accepts it :-) example

@TedLyngmo that's a good alternative. Do you want to post an answer or should I add it to mine ?

@wohlstad Add it to yours. I was actually on my way of doing that, but it's better if you do it :)

(This was initialy posted as a speculative comment, but since it got a few positive responses I though it might as well be useful as an answer.)
The problem is not that MSVC is evaluating the std::movable concept to false for an empty class (A) in general.
Looks like it is cause by the fact that A is only forward declared before it is used in MyContainer<A> c;.  When the MSVC compiler parses MyContainer<A> c;, A is still incomplete and therefore the compiler cannot verify that it respects the concept.
I am not sure whether MSVC is correct here according to the standard or gcc+clang.
Possible workarounds:

Moving A's definition above B's solves the problem for all 3 compilers.
See demo1.

Alteratively (as commented above) if you must define A after B, you can add a template parameter and make A a default for it (you can also add a static_assert to make sure no other class is used). This also works on all 3 compilers.
See demo2.



I am not absolutely sure that MSVC behavior is correct here, so submitted new issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-concept-std::movable-evaluated-to/10793048
In the accepted answer there are two working workarounds, but for build performance reasons I would prefer to keep A incomplete by the time of B's definition, and not to make B a template.
Another workaround that makes the code compatible with all 3 compilers is to add sizeof(T)>0 && in the beginning of requires-clauses of A:
template<class T>
struct MyContainer {
    MyContainer() = default;
    explicit MyContainer( std::size_t ) requires( sizeof(T)>0 && std::default_initializable<T> );
    void resize( std::size_t ) requires( sizeof(T)>0 && std::movable<T> && std::default_initializable<T> ) {}
};

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7E1bzrTeE
Apparently, when MSVC compiler parses MyContainer<A> c; and A is incomplete, the compiler short-circuit on sizeof(T)>0 && and do not cache other concepts till A is complete.
